# Removing commas used as thousand separators in dollar price amounts in longer strings using Scala regex

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to remove the , in dollar values in a string. For example I have a string: `val str = "Hello the cost is $323,999 and it has 3 modes 1,2, and 3"`

I basically want to get the output: `"Hello the cost is $323999 and it has 3 modes 1,2, and 3"`

I used the regex:

```
val pattern = """\$([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)""".r
val replacedStr = pattern replaceAllIn (str, m => m.group(1).replace(",", ""))
```

The issue is that due to the `$3` in the regex match, scala is trying to find a group 3 in the regex match and giving me `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 3`

How do I get rid of this issue?

Comment: That's strange. I just tried this example and it worked fine.

Comment: http://goo.gl/9J87pA this is the working example I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dollar symbol back when replacing, but escape it with double backslashes:

```
val pattern = """\$([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)""".r
val replacedStr = pattern replaceAllIn (str, m => "\\$" + m.group(1).replace(",", ""))
                                                  ^^^^^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/5VNujG)

You need to tell the regular expression compiler to ignore the dollar symbol, but since it is Java `String`, two backslashes must be used to get a literal backslash into the `String`.